# __init__ and __str__ to handle files

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

I have a text file a.txt. I want to perform some preprocess on it like remove punct. and split it into words.

I have written the following code to perform few operations.

```
class pre:
    def __init__(self,textfilepath):  
        self.textfilepath = textfilepath                            
    def __str__(self,textfilepath): 
        return str(textfilepath)                                                            
    def process(textpathfile):
        with open(textpathfile, r) as abc:
            a = abc.translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)
            a = a.split(' ')
            return a
pre("a.txt")
```

I tried executing it.But it gave an error pre doesn't take arguments. Can any one help me with how to do this? Thanks all.

Comment: cannot reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass arguments to `__str__`.  Instead you can access them through the properties of `self`:

```
class pre:
    def __init__(self,textfilepath):
        self.textfilepath = textfilepath

    def __str__(self):
        return self.textfilepath

    def process(self):
        with open(self.textfilepath, r) as abc:
            a = abc.translate(string.maketrans("",""), string.punctuation)
            a = a.split(' ')
            return a

p = pre("a.txt")
print(p)

filedata = p.process()
print(filedata)
```

Comment: It is just printing the file name as output. Not printing the file data. @CalebGoodman

Comment: @parushu you need to *call* the `process` method first.  I added an update as an example.

Comment: Now it is giving an error "process() is missing  1 required positional argument:'textfilepath' @CalebGoodman

Comment: remove the `textfilepath` argument from process.  You don't need it since you access it through `self`.  See my code for an example.

Comment: pre object doesn't have attribute textfilepath is the error now @CalebGoodman

Comment: @parushu thats because it was actually `textpathfile`.  I just updated my code with the fix.